# Angular Material : How to select a specific mat-cell in mat-table?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat table which displays list of Devices.

[image: Screenshot List of Devices]

The code for it is

```
<mat-table [dataSource] = "deviceDataList">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="numbers">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
             <div class="search-container">
                   <mat-form-field class="search-form-field no-line" floatLabel="never">
                         <button mat-button matPrefix mat-icon-button aria-label="Search" (click)="applyFilter()">
                               <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
                         </button>
                    <input matInput [(ngModel)] = "searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
                         <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" *ngIf="searchKey" (click)="onSearchClear()">
                               <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                         </button>
                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell [ngClass]="{'mat-style':true, 'mat-selected-style':btnValue}"  (click)="onDeviceSelect(element)" *matCellDef="let element">
                                <!-- {{element.model.instrument.VIN}}  -->
                                {{element.VIN}} 
                            </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
                            <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
                                Loading Data...
                            </mat-footer-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
                            <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
                                No Data.
                            </mat-footer-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                        <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide':deviceDataList!=null}"></mat-footer-row>
                        <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(deviceDataList!=null && deviceDataList.data.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
    </mat-table>
```

Now, On clicking a particular cell I want to add a style to it, inorder to indicate that it is active. But, when I try to do it using ngClass, The style gets added to all the cells.

Like this:

[image: Screenshot Selected Device List]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare your selected value with your whole table Data

```
   onDeviceSelect(element){
    this.addClass = false;
    this.tableData.forEach(element = > {
      if(element.VIN === event.VIN) {

       this.addClass = true;
    }
    });

    }
```

in template

```
 <mat-cell [ngClass]="{'mat-selected-style':addClass}"  (click)="onDeviceSelect(element)" *matCellDef="let element">
                                <!-- {{element.model.instrument.VIN}}  -->
                                {{element.VIN}} 
                            </mat-cell>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer upinder I had tried this approach and it won't work because when you apply the style on click of the cell, it will get applied to all the cells, since all the cells have same class.

Answer (score 0):

What you need, is to save the current clicked/selected cell and then bind the conditional styling on it. Something like this:

```
public currentCell;
public onClick(cell): void{
this.currentCell = cell;
}
```

in template you would do:

```
 <mat-cell [ngClass]="{'mat-selected-style':this.currentCell == cell}"  (click)="onClick(cell)" *matCellDef="let cell">
                                <!-- {{element.model.instrument.VIN}}  -->
                                {{element.VIN}} 
                            </mat-cell>
```